# Deserialize XSD and read key value

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd

This XML schema is generated using online tool which from .xml gives .xsd schema

I have XML Schema as shown here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="snapshot">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="device" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="property" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:attribute name="units" type="xs:string" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="module" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="category" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="capabilities" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="hwlocator" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="oslocator" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="ModelUID" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="DeviceUID" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="LocationUID" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="datetime" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="locale" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="snapshot" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The next thing step i did is generated vb class which looks like this :

Using the command line : `xsd.exe path.xsd /classes /language:vb /out:output`
    '

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Xml.Serialization

'
'This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=2.0.50727.3038.
'

'''<remarks/>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=true),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=false)>  _
Partial Public Class snapshot

    Private deviceField() As snapshotDevice

    Private datetimeField As String

    Private localeField As String

    Private versionField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("device", Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)>  _
    Public Property device() As snapshotDevice()
        Get
            Return Me.deviceField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.deviceField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property datetime() As String
        Get
            Return Me.datetimeField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.datetimeField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property locale() As String
        Get
            Return Me.localeField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.localeField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property version() As String
        Get
            Return Me.versionField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.versionField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=true)>  _
Partial Public Class snapshotDevice

    Private propertyField() As snapshotDeviceProperty

    Private typeField As String

    Private capabilitiesField As String

    Private nameField As String

    Private hwlocatorField As String

    Private oslocatorField As String

    Private modelUIDField As String

    Private deviceUIDField As String

    Private locationUIDField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("property", Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)>  _
    Public Property [property]() As snapshotDeviceProperty()
        Get
            Return Me.propertyField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.propertyField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property type() As String
        Get
            Return Me.typeField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.typeField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property capabilities() As String
        Get
            Return Me.capabilitiesField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.capabilitiesField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return Me.nameField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.nameField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property hwlocator() As String
        Get
            Return Me.hwlocatorField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.hwlocatorField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property oslocator() As String
        Get
            Return Me.oslocatorField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.oslocatorField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property ModelUID() As String
        Get
            Return Me.modelUIDField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.modelUIDField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property DeviceUID() As String
        Get
            Return Me.deviceUIDField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.deviceUIDField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property LocationUID() As String
        Get
            Return Me.locationUIDField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.locationUIDField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=true)>  _
Partial Public Class snapshotDeviceProperty

    Private valueField() As snapshotDevicePropertyValue

    Private keyField As String

    Private moduleField As String

    Private typeField As String

    Private categoryField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("value", Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)>  _
    Public Property value() As snapshotDevicePropertyValue()
        Get
            Return Me.valueField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.valueField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property key() As String
        Get
            Return Me.keyField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.keyField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property [module]() As String
        Get
            Return Me.moduleField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.moduleField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property type() As String
        Get
            Return Me.typeField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.typeField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property category() As String
        Get
            Return Me.categoryField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.categoryField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=true)>  _
Partial Public Class snapshotDevicePropertyValue

    Private valueField As String

    Private unitsField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property value() As String
        Get
            Return Me.valueField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.valueField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
    Public Property units() As String
        Get
            Return Me.unitsField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.unitsField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=true),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=false)>  _
Partial Public Class NewDataSet

    Private itemsField() As snapshot

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("snapshot")>  _
    Public Property Items() As snapshot()
        Get
            Return Me.itemsField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.itemsField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Now how can i deserialize this object: Going with code like this

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of snapshot)), New XmlRootAttribute("snapshotDevice"))
Dim deserialized As List(Of snapshot) = Nothing
Using file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(XMLFile)
    deserialized = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(file), List(Of snapshot))
End Using
```

My object returns nothing and i.e i want to read this selected value

[image: Example of XML file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of solutions is using the [DataSet.ReadXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.readxml?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
Dim dsPubs As New DataSet()

dsPubs.ReadXml("path.xml", XmlReadMode.Auto)

Dim dtKeys As DataTable = New DataView(dsPubs.Tables(2)).ToTable
Dim dtValues As DataTable = New DataView(dsPubs.Tables(3)).ToTable

Dim tbPairs As New DataTable
' Define columns
tbPairs.Columns.Add("ATTRIBUTE", GetType(System.String))
tbPairs.Columns.Add("ATTRIBUTE_DESC", GetType(System.String))

For I = 0 To dtKeys.Rows.Count - 1
    tbPairs.Rows.Add(dtKeys.Rows(I).Item(1).ToString, dtValues.Rows(I).Item(0).ToString)
Next

DataGridView1.DataSource = tbPairs
```